# A question about *general* linear operator $L : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensors

I'm reading a paper where the authors define a *general linear operator* in the following way:

Let $\textbf{L}^{1\times n^2}$ denote the *matrix* representing a *general* linear operator

$$L : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

with the *standard basis*. Now, how is this operator characterized, and which is the standard basis in this context?

From how it is defined I assume that it should take a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and assigning a *real* value to it..

Link to the paper: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=Syx72jC9tm

Comment: The standard basis consists of the matrices $E_{ij}$, which have a $1$ in the $ij$-position and $0$s elsewhere. Any linear functional on $\Bbb R^N$ is given by an $1\times N$ matrix with arbitrary (real) entries. There is no particular "general" linear operator.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ted said, the standard basis is given by $(E_{ij})_{i=1:n, j=1:n}$. Furthermore, by the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), any linear operator $L : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be characterized as

$$ L(X) = ⟨ A_L ∣ X ⟩_F $$

For some matrix $A_L$.

**Examples:**

- if $L=\operatorname{tr}$ is the matrix trace, then $A_{\operatorname{tr}} = _n$.
- if $L(X) = X_{ij}$ is the linear function that returns the $ij$-th entry of the input, then $A_L = E_{ij}$.

Comment: Could you provide me some (concrete) examples to make me better understand please?

Comment: @JamesArten I already did with the trace? What exactly are you struggling with?